# Replace substring of database record with another substring in Matlab

Tags: database, matlab, replace, substring

I know how to update a record and replace a sub string in another string:

```
update(conn,'tableName',{'columnName'},{'value'},'where columName=xx') %update record in database

modifiedStr = strrep(origStr, oldSubstr, newSubstr) %replaces substring with new string in another string.
```

Now i want to mix these two and change substring of a record in the database. How can we do that? I want a query to do this. Can we mix the two by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the {} brackets if you deal with only one column.

If you have a the column name and hold it in a variable columnName, you can try something similar:

```
columnName = 'product_id';
whereClause = ['where ',columName,'=',origStr];
modifiedStr = strrep(origStr, oldSubstr, newSubstr);
update(conn,'tableName',columnName,modifiedStr,whereClause);
```

Of course you don't need to use the variables you can just replace the desired string inside the update function, but I did it for clarification.

Comment: I tried this. The update query gives the error: Undefined function or variable 'modifiedStr'. Any idea what could be causing this?